# Is a status method necessary for an API?

Tags: api, rest

I am building an API and I was wondering is it worth having a method in an API that returns the status of the API whether its alive or not?

Or is this pointless, and its the API users job to be able to just make a call to the method that they need and if it doesn't return anything due to network issues they handle it as needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's quite useful to have a status returned. On the one hand, you can provide more statuses than 'alive' or not and make your API more poweful, and on the other hand, it's more useful for the user, since you can tell him exactly what's going on (e.g. 'maintainance').

But if your WebService isn't available at all due to network issues, then, of course, it's up to the user to catch that exception. But that's not the point, I guess, and it's not something you could control with your API.

Answer (score 2):

It's useless.

The information it returns is completely out of date the moment it is returned to you because the service may fail right after the status return call is dispatched.

Also, if you are load balancing the incoming requests and your status request gets routed to a failing node, the reply (or lack thereof) would look to the client like a problem with the whole API service. In the meantime, all the other nodes could be happily servicing requests. Now your client will think that the whole API service is down but subsequent requests would work just fine (assuming your load balancer would remove the failed node or restart it).

HTTP status codes returned from your application's requests are the correct way of indicating availability. Your clients of course have to be coded to tolerate and handle them.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with standard HTTP response status codes? [503 Service Unavailable](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) comes to mind.  HTTP clients should already be able to handle that without writing any code special to your API.

Now, if the service is *likely* to be unavailable frequently and it is expensive for the client to discover that but cheap for the server, then it might be appropriate to have a separate 'health check' URL that can quickly let the client know that the service is available (at the time of the GET on the health check URL).

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary most of the time. At least when it returns simple true or false. It just makes client code more complicated because it has to call one more method. Even if your client received active=true from service, next useful call may still fail. Let you client make  the calls that they need during normal execution and have them handle network, timeout and HTTP errors correctly. Very useful pattern for such cases is called [Circuit Breaker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker_design_pattern).

The reasons where status check may be useful:

- If all the normal calls are considered to be expensive there may be an advantage in first calling lightweight status-check method (just to avoid expensive call).
- Service can have different statuses and client can change its behavior depending on these statuses.

It might also be worth looking into stateful protocols like [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/).